# Debian: ./configure fails because of PKG_CHECK

Tags: configuration, makefile, debian, pkg-config

I want to build a modified version of lighttpd.
I follow this tutorial:
http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Lighttpd-Version2

This is what I've done so far

```
apt get install lighttpd
apt get install automake autoconf libtool 
cd /var/tmp
wget http://h264.code-shop.com/download/lighttpd-1.4.18_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.9.tar.gz
tar -zxvf lighttpd-1.4.18_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.9.tar.gz
wget http://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/releases-1.4.x/lighttpd-1.4.28.tar.gz
tar ...
```

after I copied all files and data to the directory and Makefile.am I entered:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-maintainer-mode --prefix=${HOME}/test/lighttpd-1.4.28
```

the console returnes:

```
    ...
        checking for pkg-config... no
        checking for libev support... ./configure: line 12184: syntax error near unexpected token `LIBEV,'
./configure: line 12184: `      PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBEV, libev, ,'
root@foo...
```

Some people solved this by installing "pkg-config". I installed this package but I still can't run the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that this version of lighttpd contains a bug. I switched from 1.4.28 to 1.4.30 and everything went good.